# jQuery adding css to only few list items in an unsorted list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 blocks of code (group of li items) each block needs a separate CSS. As the code is dynamic I can not assign IDs to li items to take it to my control. How can I add seperate CSS to 3 li items to header1, 3 li items to header 2, 3 li items to header 3

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95Z6Z/)

```
<ul class="tree">
    <li id="section">Header1 </li>
    <li> 1</li>
    <li> 2</li>
    <li> 3</li>
    <li id="section"> Header 2</li>
    <li> 4</li>
    <li> 5</li>
    <li> 6</li>
    <li id="section"> Header 3 </li>
    <li> 7</li>
    <li> 8</li>
    <li> 9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How about to change your code which generates this html by adding ids or classes?

Comment: Its not possible as its from an external framework. Do we have any other alternative?

Comment: Why not structure your `<ul>` to nest other `<ul>s` within the parent `<ul><li>`?

Comment: Having duplicate ids in the same DOM is not a good idea. I removed my answer since apparantly I was not sure what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have control on adding `id`s or `class`es to the required elements, this is the way to do it:

```
var listItems = $('.tree li');
var group = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) { //Note: You may use jquery iterator also
    var item = $(listItems[i]);
    if (item.attr('id') === 'section') {
        group++;
    }
    switch(group) {
        case 1:
            item.addClass('group1');
        break;

        case 2:
            item.addClass('group2');
        break;

        case 3:
            item.addClass('group3');
        break;
    }
}
```

Now define `group1`, `group2` and `group3` CSS classes with needed background color in your CSS and you are done!

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/RVj4k/1/

Comment: Nice idea to add class names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jQuery map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function to run your own custom logic as to what/when to apply:

```
$('.tree li').map(function(index, element){

    switch(index % 4)
    {
        case 0:
          $(element).addClass('header');
          break;
        default:
          //do nothing
          break;
    }

})
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/95Z6Z/4/)

EDIT: Following inspiration from @jstq's answer, i've changed the case statement to use modulus. It makes it more scalable.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery script:

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 12; i++ ) {
    if (i % 4 !=0)
    $(".tree li:eq("+i+")").css( "background", "red" );
}
```

You can do any conditions you want

Separate statements:

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 12; i++ ) {
    if (i % 4 !=0) 
    {
        if (i<5)
            $(".tree li:eq("+i+")").css( "background", "blue" );
        else if (i<8)
            $(".tree li:eq("+i+")").css( "background", "green" );
        else 
            $(".tree li:eq("+i+")").css( "background", "red" );
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew there was a math solution to this!

Comment: Does not do what the user has asked.

Answer (score 0):

try this as CSS

```
li:nth-child(-n+12) {
    color: red;   
}
li:nth-child(-n+8) {
    color: blue;   
}
li:nth-child(-n+4) {
    color: green;   
}
```

Source : http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Comment: What if number of children changes?

Comment: If it changes, use Javascript.. replace 12, 8 n 4 with some variable in js.. It depends whether the code is that dynamic or not. time complexities n script size are also to be considered

Comment: No of children will be dynamic.

Comment: Do not write fragile code! There you go - with dynamic number of children this code falls flat. See the solution I have given and see the fiddle. It works whatever is number of children.

Comment: @RaviH People in glass houses should not throw stones. Your answer has the same problem.

Comment: @jammykam Absolutely not! Analyze the problem and the solution together. See the fiddle. Fork the fiddle and add more li's within each section and see what happens. Then comment.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/zc22r/ But obviously I missed something in the question since your answer was accepted. I apologize.

Comment: You guy have so lots of time n energy to waste, fighting with each other.. !!